# JDBCMetadataStore vs transaction manager

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-integration, spring-integration-jdbc

As per documentation, **JDBCMetadataStore** requires an instance of **DataSourceTransactionManager** and this makes sense. What if I'm using JPA as primary transaction manager in the application? How can I tell to **JDBCMetadataStore** which transaction manager it should make use when calling the **@Transactional** methods - assuming I have to have 2 flavours of transaction manager beans in the application. Suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to extend that `JdbcMetadataStore` and override all the transactional methods with delegation to super and `@Transactional` with the specific TX manager:

```
public class MyJdbcMetadataStore extends JdbcMetadataStore {

    public MyJdbcMetadataStore(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional("jdbcTransactionManager")
    public String putIfAbsent(String key, String value) {
        return super.putIfAbsent(key, value);
    }

}
```